# Order of construction/initialization?

Tags: java, android

***NB:** I added the `android` tag because I've only tried this on Android's own VM, as part of an app. Other JVMs might or might not behave the same way.*

---

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```java
public class Test {
    public static class Base {
        public final Object base = new Object();

        public Base() {
            print();
        }

        public void print() {
            System.err.println(String.format("base = %s", base));
        }
    }

    public static class Outer extends Base {
        public final Object member = new Object();

        public Outer() {
            super();
        }

        @Override
        public void print() {
            super.print();
            System.err.println(String.format("member = %s", member));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Outer();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
base = java.lang.Object@9a9e0fa
member = null
```

Why is `member` NULL? I was under the impression any nonstatic class fields are initialized before the constructor runs.

Comment: IMHO the real problem here is that Java doesn't follow the C++ rule of not calling derived class overrides while in the base class constructor. It's one of the few Java design decisions I strongly disagree with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was under the impression any nonstatic class fields are initialized before the constructor runs.

Your impression is / was incorrect.

What actually happens is that *all* superclass initialization for an object happens before *any* subclass initialization for the object.

<sup>The above rule-of-thumb is for object instance initialization only.  Class (i.e. `static`) initialization is a bit more complicated.  But this question is about instance initialization.</sup>

The process is described in detail in [JLS 12.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5).  The relevant part is this:

> Just before a reference to the newly created object is returned as the
>   result, the indicated constructor is processed to initialize the new
>   object using the following procedure:
>
> 1. Assign the arguments for the constructor to newly created parameter variables for this constructor invocation.
> 2. If this constructor begins with an explicit constructor invocation (§8.8.7.1) of another constructor in the same class (using this), then
>      evaluate the arguments and process that constructor invocation
>      recursively using these same five steps. If that constructor
>      invocation completes abruptly, then this procedure completes abruptly
>      for the same reason; otherwise, continue with step 5.
> 3. This constructor does not begin with an explicit constructor invocation of another constructor in the same class (using this). If
>      this constructor is for a class other than Object, then this
>      constructor will begin with an explicit or implicit invocation of a
>      superclass constructor (using super). **Evaluate the arguments and
>      process that superclass constructor invocation recursively using these
>      same five steps.** If that constructor invocation completes abruptly,
>      then this procedure completes abruptly for the same reason. Otherwise,
>      continue with step 4.
> 4. Execute the instance initializers and instance variable initializers for this class, assigning the values of instance variable
>      initializers to the corresponding instance variables, in the
>      left-to-right order in which they appear textually in the source code
>      for the class. If execution of any of these initializers results in an
>      exception, then no further initializers are processed and this
>      procedure completes abruptly with that same exception. Otherwise,
>      continue with step 5.
> 5. Execute the rest of the body of this constructor. If that execution completes abruptly, then this procedure completes abruptly
>      for the same reason. Otherwise, this procedure completes normally.

Note the sentence that I have highlight.  When you take that in the context of the rest, that means that the constructor body for `Base()` runs before the initialization of the instance fields for `Outer`.

---

> Other JVMs might or might not behave the same way.

In fact all JVMs should behave this way.  This is how the Java language is specified to behave.

Comment: do you guys memorize these things? how do you remember all this? how do you find a link to `jls-12.5` ? Just curious if there's a logical way to remember such things

Comment: Of course I don't remember the links / sections.  I look them up in the JLS ToC!  (I mean, sure, I'm familiar enough with the JLS to know where in the ToC to look.  But that's not a hard thing to do.  The JLS has a clear logical structure to it.  And it is well cross-linked.)

Comment: @ArunGowda You only have to remember the second sentence: "*all* superclass initialization happens before *any* initialization of the subclass".

Comment: Huh, well that's unfortunate in my specific case. Now I have to come up with a workaround. Thanks.